# Iphone, Obtaining a List of countries in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a menu that let's a user select a country. Exactly like that in the contacts.app country menu within the address field.

Does anyone know a simple way of getting a list of countries? I have used NSLocale to generate an array of countries but it's only the country codes unfortunately and not the human readable equivalent. I don't want 'GB' I want Great Britain.

Comment: This is not working with iOS 8.1 Simulator see this post :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613011/xcode-6-1-ios-8-1-nslocale-displaynameforkey-nslocaleidentifier-return-nil

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `[[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode]` (where countryCode is an item in your list of country codes) to get the country's name in the user's current locale.

Answer (score 94):

Thanks chuck.

If anyone is interested or wanted to find the same solution here is my code for a sorted array of countries.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];

NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray) {

    NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];

}

[sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

**Swift:**

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let countryArray = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes()
var unsortedCountryArray:[String] = []
for countryCode in countryArray {
    let displayNameString = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)
    if displayNameString != nil {
        unsortedCountryArray.append(displayNameString!)
    }
}
let sortedCountryArray = sorted(unsortedCountryArray, <)
```

**Swift 3**

```
    let locale = NSLocale.current
    let unsortedCountries = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.map { locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)! }
    let sortedCountries = unsortedCountries.sorted()
```

Comment: You might want to initialize `sortedCountryArray` with capacity of `countryArray.count`.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to define locale..
and there is too much autoreleased memory, which might be critical, ye never know. so create autoreleased pool inside the for loop as well.
I've this:

```
NSMutableArray * countriesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"] autorelease];

NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]; 
for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray) 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [countriesArray addObject:displayNameString];
    [pool release];

}

[countriesArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
let locale = Locale.current
let countries = Locale.isoRegionCodes.map {
    locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)!
}.sorted()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as above, just uses `flatMap` to be shorter and swiftier.

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
var countries = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes().flatMap { countryCode in
    return locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)
}
countries.sortInPlace()
```

Answer (score -1):

Got this one working on playgrounds

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "FI")
let unsortedCountries = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes.flatMap { locale.localizedString(forCountryCode: $0) }
let sortedCountries = unsortedCountries.sorted()
```