# Iphone, Obtaining a List of countries from MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, nslocale

Is it possible to replicate what the code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502764/iphone-obtaining-a-list-of-countries-in-an-nsarray) does in MonoTouch?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
foreach(string countryCode in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes){
 // How to convert this objective-c code to c#?
 // [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode]
}
```

Comment: It seems possible, there's an NSLocale class etc... what have you tried?  Are you hitting a specific error?

Comment: Question updated to include c# code so far

Comment: yeah - I started to type the answer (knowing C# but not Mono expert) and I got as far as you.  Docs look missing and couldn't find how to translate the country code into a friendly description string.  As you iterate, add the description (if you figure that out) to a List<string> and sort that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly a quick look shows that **[displayNameForKey:value:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** to be (currently as of 4.2.x) missing from MonoTouch (and MonoMac) bindings. I'll look into implementing it and will update this entry once done.

**UPDATE** : Source code to work around the missing binding

```
    public void DisplayCountryCodeNames ()
    {
        NSLocale current = NSLocale.CurrentLocale;
        IntPtr handle = current.Handle;
        IntPtr selDisplayNameForKeyValue = new Selector ("displayNameForKey:value:").Handle;
        foreach (var countryCode in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes) {
            using (var key = new NSString ("kCFLocaleCountryCodeKey")) {
                using (var nsvalue = new NSString (countryCode)) {
                    string ret = NSString.FromHandle (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (handle, selDisplayNameForKeyValue, key.Handle, nsvalue.Handle));
                    Console.WriteLine ("{0} -> {1}", countryCode, ret);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Adapt to your liking and have fun with MonoTouch!

p.s. I'll update the bindings so it will be included in future releases for MonoTouch in a more *proper* API ;-)

Comment: Btw, looking at implementing a Countries picklist, has anyone done this before?

Comment: That should be made another question (so more people will read it than this comment)

Comment: Was this binding ever added to MonoTouch? I currently need to get the names of currencies (NSLocaleCurrencyCode), but the above code, even with "kCFLocaleCurrencyCodeKey", isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is certainly possible.  MonoTouch wraps the iOS API in C# classes so that you can do anything in C# that you can do in Objective-C.  Unfortunately you have to download the trial version to get the documentation.  I imagine the code would look something like this:

```
foreach(string countryCode in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes){
  string CountryName = NSLocale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, countryCode);
}
```