# Obtaining list of countries and main cities in an UITableView

Tags: ios

I have 2 drop down boxes for users to select the country and city. Ho can i get all the countries and cities? Is there any easiest way to obtain this? Please help me. I'm new to the iPhone programming.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502764/iphone-obtaining-a-list-of-countries-in-an-nsarray

Comment: Ok but how can I get the list of country code

Comment: Did you read all of the answers to that question?